# Granger causality on categorical variable

Tags: r, time-series, categorical-data, granger-causality

Is it possible to run a Granger Causality test with the dependent variable as a categorical variable and the independent variable as a numeric variable? I'm working in `R` and running into errors due to the categorical variable because how does one difference a categorical variable to make it stationary, for example?

I searched for an answer but all I could find were discussions and papers regarding causation between two or more categorical variables or other more complicated analyses.

Here's a toy data set as an `R` data frame.

```
data.frame(var1 = c(1,3,5,3,4,5,7,9,6,3), 
           var2 = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C"))
   var1 var2
1     1    A
2     3    A
3     5    A
4     3    A
5     4    A
6     5    B
7     7    B
8     9    B
9     6    B
10    3    C
```

I'd like to understand if `var1` or its lags Granger-cause `var2`.